# Run-time error when executing SQL in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am getting `Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14) Incorrect syntax new '11999999'` when trying to pull data in from a SQL server database in to a Recordset in VBA, this is my first time using VBA so forgive the lack of perfection.

My code is as follows;

```
Set connection = New ADODB.Connection
Dim newData As ADODB.Recordset

connection.ConnectionString = "my connection string" 'not posting this for security reasons'
connection.Open

Set newData = connectionExecute(BSMARTOpenFaults )
```

I have my query stored as a multiline string as I prefer it becuase it looks better with SQL statements.

```
Private Const BSMARTOpenFaults = "select count(*) from call" _
& "where (" _
& "   call_id between 11000000 and 11999999" _
& "or call_id between 12000000 and 12999999" _
& "or call_id between 14000000 and 14999999" _
& "or call_id between 16000000 and 19999999" _
& "or call_id between 26000000 and 26999999" _
& "or call_id between 31000000 and 31999999" _
& "or call_id between 73000000 and 73999999)" _
& "and call_status <> 2 -- all open calls" _
& "and call_type = 'FT'"
```

Judging by the error its falling on the SQL query (or its just a coincedence that the two numbers are the same) but I am not sure on how to fix it because when I run the query on SQL Server Management Studio the query executes and returns a result (21 to be exact) so it is confusing me as to why it won't execute and returns an invalid syntax error when attempting in VBA, is this an incorrect way of formatting SQL statements in VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no newlines between the numbers and `OR` keywords. Your statement looks like :

```
and 11999999or call_id between 12000000 and 12999999or and
```

Add a space after the number and/or before the keywords

Comment: thanks, didnt realise i had forgotten the spaces inbetween the quotes and because obviously my normal form of it for running in management studio doesnt have the qutoes i didnt realise

Answer (score 2):

General tip what to do, when you are debugging SQL in VBA:

1. declare the `BSMARTOpenFaults` as a public for the test.
2. Go to the immediate window and write `?BSMARTOpenFaults`
3. See the output.
4. Examine the output.
5. See that `callwhere` is one word.
6. Change the code to `Const BSMARTOpenFaults = "select count(*) from call " _` so the words are 2.

Answer (score 2):

Don't skip the spaces at the end of each section of the string. At the moment your string returns:

```
select count(*) from callwhere (...
```

And `callwhere` is probably not a table in your schema. Same issue is there for the OR clauses. Try this:

```
Private Const BSMARTOpenFaults = "select count(*) from call " _
& "where (" _
& "   call_id between 11000000 and 11999999 " _
& "or call_id between 12000000 and 12999999 " _
& "or call_id between 14000000 and 14999999 " _
& "or call_id between 16000000 and 19999999 " _
& "or call_id between 26000000 and 26999999 " _
& "or call_id between 31000000 and 31999999 " _
& "or call_id between 73000000 and 73999999) " _
& "and call_status <> 2 " _
& "and call_type = 'FT'"
```